# How do I delete data on InfluxDB2 deployed with Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb

I have a web platform hosted on Azure which uses, among other things, an influxdb2 database which is deployed with Kubernetes. I can't manage to implement a feature allowing me to delete data between two dates on the platform. However, I can read the data. The code below works locally but no longer works on the deployed version.

Does anyone have any idea why this is or know of another way of doing it?

```
client = InfluxDBClient(
            url=self.url,
            token=self.token,
            org=self.org
)
delete_api = client.delete_api()
start_time = utc_start
end_time = utc_stop
bucket = self.bucket
predicate1 = '_measurement="INAmean"'

result1 = delete_api.delete(start=start_time, stop=end_time, bucket=bucket, predicate=predicate1, org=self.org)
```